# poco Lib dosnt compile in vs express 9

Tags: c++, compilation, poco

im trying to compile the poco lib in vs express 2008 
but im keep getting this error :
poco-1.3.6p2\foundation\src\eventlogchannel.cpp(40) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pocomsg.h': No such file or directory
no i have the mc.exe in my sdk and all the paths in the IDE are seams to be right 
and nada . 
does any one have experience with this lib ?

Answer (score 1):

First try searching for that file in the source you downloaded. If you can't find it, you're missing a file.

If it's there, you're missing a directory include - go to `eventlogchannel.cpp` right click on the `#include` and select `Open document`. An error dialog will popup, showing you every directory that was searched - you should be able to confirm that the directory with `'pocomsg.h'` in it isn't there. You can then add it to the project settings.

Comment: well i know i need to build it with mc.exe but when i try to compile it with the compiler it say it can't find this file that is the product of the mc.exe

Answer (score 0):

pocomsg.h should be found in ../Foundation/src/

It doesn't contain too much important stuff though, the main guts of it are a couple of defines:

```
#define POCO_CTG_FATAL                   0x00000001L
#define POCO_CTG_CRITICAL                0x00000002L
#define POCO_CTG_ERROR                   0x00000003L
#define POCO_CTG_WARNING                 0x00000004L
#define POCO_CTG_NOTICE                  0x00000005L
#define POCO_CTG_INFORMATION             0x00000006L
#define POCO_CTG_DEBUG                   0x00000007L
#define POCO_CTG_TRACE                   0x00000008L
#define POCO_MSG_LOG                     0x00001000L
```

Are the guts of the file. Try defining them yourself in Poco.h, possibly.

As a side note, it says in the header that the file is automatically generated from pocomsg.mc, so try running a script prior to compile, possibly those in the Poco root directory?